# How to add a voice to text-to-speech in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, text-to-speech-voices

How to add a new voice for text-to-speech in Windows 8. After spending hours in google and bing I could not find an answer to a simple question: is it possible to add, say, French voice to Microsoft text-to-speech in Windows 8 (actually I need Russian). Please help.

Comment: Yes;  windows by default as this feature in the ease of use feature set.  How well it will work will depend the quality of the language pack.